# java String replace method works but throwing error with replaceAll

Tags: java, string

I have a string andn I want to replace { to \{ ... When I use replace method then it works but when I use replaceAll then it is giving error like `Illegal repetition`
What is the reason?

```
String s = "One{ two } three {{{ four}";
System.out.println(s.replace("{", "\\{"));
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("{", "\\{"));
```

Expected output is - One\{ two } three \{\{\{ four}

Comment: replaceAll's first parameter must be regex, it's not treated as string or char.

Comment: how does this compiles?

Comment: @Lrrr there is no issue in compilation I faced.

Comment: please, post your expected output...

Comment: try `s.replaceAll("\\{", "\\\\{")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained `String::replaceAll` expects `regex` and `Strinng::replace` expects `charSequence`. So you must escape both `\` and `{` in order to match as you expect.

```
String s = "One{ two } three {{{ four}";

System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(s.replace("{", "\\{"));
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\{", "\\\\{"));
```

Output:

```
One{ two } three {{{ four}
One\{ two } three \{\{\{ four}
One\{ two } three \{\{\{ four}
```

Answer (score 2):

String replaceAll expects regex whereas replace expects charSequence. Hence modifying the code

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\{", "\\{"));
```

Should work.

Comment: @JordiCastilla the post has been modified after I answered the question. If we need the output after modification it would lokk like as follows: System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\{", "\\\\{"));